# How to pass object to a function in this scenario

Tags: python

I have the following piece of code:

```
 NameX.functionA(functionB(Dictionary["___"]))
```

Instead of *_* I would like to make a reference to NameX in the form of a string, so that the program interprets it as

```
 NameX.functionA(functionB(Dictionary["NameX"]))
```

How can I do this? I tried to use str(self), but it is clearly wrong.

Thanks

Comment: In its current state, this is now answerable. What's "NameX", i.e. why "NameX" and not "quux"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is `NameX.__name__` perhaps what you want?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
Name.__name__
```

on an *uninitialized* object and

```
Name.__class__.__name__
```

on an *initialized* object.

Answer (score 0):

Abusive but it works:

```
>>> def getvarname(var):
    d = globals()
    for n in d:
        if d[n] is var:
            return n
    return None

>>> class NameX: pass

>>> getvarname(NameX)
'NameX'
```

Works on things that aren't just classes, too:

```
>>> inst1 = NameX()
>>> getvarname(inst1)
'inst1'
```

You might be shot if this ends up in real code, though.